# SAPUI5 Avatar - Display of an image (streamed from backend) doesn't work

Tags: image, stream, sapui5, avatar

In an `ObjectPageLayout` I want to show a picture with the embedded `sap.f.Avatar` (shaped as a circle). The picture is saved as a `rawstring` in SAP backend and streamed via oData (media). When I set the URI via the method `setSrc` for an image it works, same for Avatar doesn't work? So how do you bind a backend streamed image to the avatar control?

**Works:**

```
Image.setSrc(**/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_SERVICE_SRV/ImageSet('1234')/$value).
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
Avatar.setSrc(**/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_SERVICE_SRV/ImageSet('1234')/$value).
```

Same problem was already [discussed here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/11088699/how-to-display-retrieved-photo-media-stream-data-a.html), but with no solution.

**Avatar Example:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answer by Лидия Копылова worked for me:

> The reason of this bug is because if you work with Avatar control it
>   uses a css property background-image that fails because of single
>   quotes in the beginning of this property and in the string inside.
>
> background-image(**'**.... ImageSet(**'** 1234')...');

I had to change my single quotes to `%27` and the Avatar control started working.
So your changed code would be:

```
Avatar.setSrc(**/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_SERVICE_SRV/ImageSet(%271234%27)/$value).
```

Also worth noting, I am currently using SAPui5 verion 1.52.34, but when using 1.60.1, the Avatar control worked without changing the single quotes to `%27`. So if you are able to upgrade ui5 versions, this will probably be a viable option as well.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this bug is because if you work with Avatar control it uses a css property background-image that fails because of single quotes in the beginning of this property and in the string inside.

```css
background-image(**'**.... ImageSet(**'** 1234')...');
```